# check about performance of two queries

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, plsql

Would you mind help me which query performing better and which one is more recommended in oracle database?

**first query:**

```
Select t2_c1,t1_c3,t1_c4,t3_c1

from t1,t2,t3

where   t1_c1 = t2_c1   and    t1_c2=t3_c2
```

**Plan:**

```
ID  PID Operation   Name    Rows    Bytes   Cost    CPU Cost    IO Cost Temp space  IN-OUT  PQ Dist PStart  PStop
0       SELECT STATEMENT        22362   829K    82      82                    
1   0     HASH JOIN     22362   829K    82      82                    
2   1       TABLE ACCESS FULL   CUSTOMER    87  2349    2       2                     
3   1       TABLE ACCESS FULL   MASTER  22362   240K    79      79
```

**Second query:**

```
select (select t2_c2 from t2 where t1_c1 = t2_c1),  t1_c3,  t1_c4,  t3_c1

from t1, t3

where t1_c2=t3_c2
```

**Plan:**

```
ID  PID Operation   Name    Rows    Bytes   Cost    CPU Cost    IO Cost Temp space  IN-OUT  PQ Dist PStart  PStop
0       SELECT STATEMENT        22362   240K    79      79                    
1   0     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   CUSTOMER    1   27  2       2                     
2   1       INDEX RANGE SCAN    SYS.IDX_CUSTOMER_V_CUST 1       1       1                     
3   0     TABLE ACCESS FULL MASTER  22362   240K    79      79
```

Comment: My problem with that is ORA-02402: PLAN_TABLE not found :D

Comment: Join would be better, Instead of making a call in `SELECT`. So First Query should be good.

Comment: I arrange Plan Table, the result shows that second query perform better. I had index for t1_c2, t2_c2 and t3_c2 as well.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar Actually, there has to be no differences, because oracle optimizer rewrites queries before choosing the best execution plan

Comment: @rima The fact that the second query performs better makes sense, because the explain plan shows that the first query needs 2 full table scans, whereas the second one uses a range scan and table access by index.

Comment: I thought that join table is better than subquery always...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you would like return less than 4% of line on table MASTER I recommend you the second one, but if you will return all lines on table MASTER the first plan is much better.

Any question just let me know.

Thanks.